Quarkus Reactive Panache Test: "No current Vertx context found" error in Panache.withTransaction()
I am working on a Quarkus project where I'm using Hibernate Reactive with Panache for non-blocking database operations. My service method creates a user inside a transaction using Panache.withTransaction().
This is the service method:
public Uni<Auth> createUser(Auth authRequest) {
        User user = new User(authRequest);
        String passwordHash = Password.hash(authRequest.getPassword()).withArgon2().getResult();
        user.setPasswordHash(passwordHash);
        return Panache.withTransaction(() -> PanacheEntityBase.persist(user))
            .onItem().transform(success -> {
                log.info("Successfully created user, email: {}", authRequest.getEmail());
                return authRequest;
            })
                .onFailure(ConstraintViolationException.class)
                .transform(ex -> {
                    log.error("User already exists, email: {}", user.getEmail());
                    throw new AccountDoesNotExistsException(Errors.ACCOUNT_ALREADY_EXISTS + user.getEmail());
                });
    }

Here is my test case:
package org.acme.service;

import io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.Panache;
import io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.PanacheEntityBase;
import io.quarkus.panache.mock.PanacheMock;
import io.quarkus.test.InjectMock;
import io.quarkus.test.TestReactiveTransaction;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import io.smallrye.mutiny.CompositeException;
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import org.acme.entity.User;
import org.acme.model.Auth;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;

@QuarkusTest
class AuthServiceTest {

    private Auth authRequest;
    @Inject
    private AuthService authService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        authRequest = new Auth();
        authRequest.setEmail("mock@gmail.com");
        authRequest.setPassword("m)ck!123POwed");
        authRequest.setFirstName("mock first name");
        authRequest.setLastName("mcok last name");
        PanacheMock.mock(User.class);
        PanacheMock.mock(Panache.class);
    }

    @Test
    void givenValidAuthRequest_whenCreateUserCalled_thenReturnAuthResponse() {
        Mockito.when(Panache.withTransaction(any())).thenReturn(Uni.createFrom().item(authRequest));
        Auth authResponse = authService.createUser(authRequest).await().indefinitely();
        assertEquals(authRequest.getEmail(), authResponse.getEmail());
    }

    @Test
    void givenValidAuthRequest_whenCreateUserCalled_thenThrowsException() {
        Mockito.when(User.persist(any(User.class), any(Object.class))).thenReturn(Uni.createFrom().failure(new IOException("Mock exception")));
        assertThrows(CompositeException.class, () -> authService.createUser(authRequest).await().indefinitely());
    }

}

When I run the test, I encounter the following error:
No current Vertx context found
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current Vertx context found
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.common.runtime.SessionOperations.vertxContext(SessionOperations.java:191)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.common.runtime.SessionOperations.withSession(SessionOperations.java:110)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.common.runtime.SessionOperations.withTransaction(SessionOperations.java:88)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.common.runtime.WithTransactionInterceptor.intercept(WithTransactionInterceptor.java:20)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.common.runtime.WithTransactionInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:42)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:30)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:27)
    at org.acme.service.AuthService_Subclass.createUser(Unknown Source)
    at org.acme.service.AuthService_ClientProxy.createUser(Unknown Source)
    at org.acme.service.AuthServiceTest.givenValidAuthRequest_whenCreateUserCalled_thenReturnAuthResponse(AuthServiceTest.java:46)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.runExtensionMethod(QuarkusTestExtension.java:973)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestMethod(QuarkusTestExtension.java:823)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)

What I’ve Tried:

Mocking Panache.withTransaction() to return a Uni<Auth>.
Mocking User.persist().
Attempting different variations of mocking, but I always hit the error No current Vertx context found.
What I Understand:
This seems related to Quarkus' reactive model and the need for a Vert.x context in the test.
I believe I am not properly handling the asynchronous behavior of Panache.withTransaction() in the test environment.

Questions:

How can I set up my test to run within the correct Vert.x context to prevent this error?
Is there a specific way to mock reactive operations with Panache in Quarkus?
Is there an alternative approach to testing Panache.withTransaction() that avoids this issue?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!


You are probably missing the io.quarkus.test.vertx.RunOnVertxContext annotation:
@Test
@RunOnVertxContext
public void givenValidAuthRequest_whenCreateUserCalled_thenReturnAuthResponse() {
  ...
}

You can check the documentation for a full example.
